# Jbutton to retrieve JText.getText and search from arraylist with two values

Tags: java, swing

i'm facing a problem when select a Jbutton to retrieve JText.getText and search from arraylist with two values (string,double). As follows is my code pls help. Thanks

```
public void initCards(){
    StudentCard s1 = new StudentCard("1234567",5.00);
    EZLinkCard.add(s1); 
    StudentCard s2 = new StudentCard("1001001",0.00);
    EZLinkCard.add(s2);
    AdultCard a1 = new AdultCard ("5678901",20.00);
    EZLinkCard.add(a1);
}

public EZLinkCard searchCard(String cardNum){      
    for(int a=0; a < EZLinkCard.size(); a++){// Loop for print methods
        System.out.println(a);
        EZLinkCard p = (EZLinkCard)EZLinkCard.get(a);
        if (p.getCardNum().equals(cardNum)){ 
            return p;  
        } 
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Key in valid card number" );
        }
    } 

    if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Retrive card information")) {         
        String cardNum = TCardNumber.getText();
        CardList c = new CardList();
        EZLinkCard p ;
        p = c.searchCard("cardNum");
        String z = Double.toString(p.getBalance());
        TCardBalance.setText(z); 
    }
```

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at ezlink.MainMenu$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(MainMenu.java:86)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased
```

(BasicButtonListener.java:252)

```
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
```

(ProtectionDomain.java:76)

```
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
```

(ProtectionDomain.java:87)

```
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege
```

(ProtectionDomain.java:76)

```
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters
```

(EventDispatchThread.java:211)

```
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy
```

(EventDispatchThread.java:117)

```
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please tell us what the error is, including the exception stack trace. Otherwise, you'll need to tell us what the problem is, so we can help you.

Comment: We need a lot more info from you to solve this, as others have pointed out. Also, lots of weird stuff or bad practices, such as having a return in the middle of a method, and a test for an action command beyond that. Are these code fragments or your actual code? It would be nice to know why you are casting an EZLinkCard to an EZLinkCard, and how it is defined. Lots of questions raised here.

Comment: i think is the calling of the array out and to print the value

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but maybe you're getting the "Please key in a valid card number" popup multiple times, even if you enter a valid card number? If so, you need to move the `JOptionPane` call outside the `for` loop, like so...

```
public EZLinkCard searchCard(String cardNum){      
    for(int a=0; a < EZLinkCard.size(); a++){// Loop for print methods
        System.out.println(a);
        EZLinkCard p = (EZLinkCard)EZLinkCard.get(a);
        if (p.getCardNum().equals(cardNum)){ 
            return p;  
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Key in valid card number" );
}
```

That's the best I can come up with, without knowing what the actual problem is that you're experiencing.

Comment: this does print the Joptionp.panel but it doesnt search thru the arraylist.. is my looping done corrently?